# Windows+X shortcut key doesn't work anymore in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I usually use `Windows+X` shortcut key to access `Windows Mobility Center`.
But it doesn't work anymore.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of disabling the `Windows Mobility Center` and it is hard to know how it was done in your case, the most common one is by a registry key. To restore (If it was done this way) Do the following:

Open up the `Registry Editor` and expand to:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

Take a look for the key `NoWinKeys` and simply delete it.

[Here is a .reg file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/xk11olnmmfe/WinKeyDelete.reg) that can be directly run to do the above job.

If this doesn't work, please say and I will try to write a guide for some of the other methods.

Comment: But I wanna enable it!!!

Comment: Sorry, This should do the job, I just phrased it bad, I will try to edit...

Comment: Thanks Wil, I did a Virus Scan, It have fixed with it!!!